# how to access object property from inside function in javascript, is it possible?

Tags: javascript

I have a function and an object inside that function. I am returning the object. How can I call the function and then get the `obj.a` in `console.log();`?

```js
function _() {
  var obj = {};

  obj.a = "one";
  obj.b = "two";

  return obj;
}

console.log(_);
```

Comment: you just need to call the `_` function. `console.log(_().a);`

Comment: you're not accessing anything in the function but rather an attribute on the obj it's returning. e.g. `var myObj = _(); console.log(myObj.a);`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/16wmtb7f/

Comment: I don't understand why the question is downvoted? Even though the asker had a simple syntax error, It's a fair question that demonstrates code and attempt.

Comment: thanks phillip Chan

Comment: thanks Amir for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply execute the function (`_()`, which will return an object), then access its inner properties using dot notation as you normally would:

```js
function _() {
  var obj = {};

  obj.a = "one";
  obj.b = "two";

  return obj;
}

console.log(_().a);
console.log(_().b);
```

You may want to consider storing the result of executing the function as a separate variable first though, rather than executing it repeatedly every time you wish to access a property from the object it returns.